# Do "HttpError"s cause cold starts in Google Cloud callable functions?

Tags: firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

[this google cloud functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) says

> Uncaught exceptions or executions that crash the process can result in cold starts

Does that also apply to callable functions, defined with `functions.https.onCall`? My understanding is that the proper way to handle failures was to thow an `HttpsError`, e.g., `throw new HttpsError("failed-precondition", "...")`

Am I incorrect in that, or are `HttpsError`s handled differently? What about other uncaught errors? Are they logged in cloud functions logs, or just returned to the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would fully expect that HttpsError is internally caught by the functions framework so that it can execute code to issue the correct response to the caller.  You can examine the source code yourself [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions).

The point that the documentation is trying to make is essentially that uncaught exceptions could mean something truly disastrous happened, and that it's not safe to leave the server instance around any more to serve further requests.  Therefore, another server instance might take its place on the next request if needed, causing a cold start.  If you want to minimize cold starts, you should strive to capture non-fatal errors and decide for yourself if they warrant a server restart.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like non-HttpsErrors lead to a log being generated [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/f9ecee4214e27bbe0f9e52323729506eba150a50/src/common/providers/https.ts#L776-L780) and get converted to "internal" HttpsErrors. But I don't see anything that could result in a cold start, or for that matter I don't see anything mapping HttpsErrors to various return status codes. Wouldn't that be handled by some closed-source Google code that actually manages the Cloud Functions runtime?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck getting an answer if you post to [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk).

Comment: That's a useful resource I didn't know existed! Thank you.